# Three phase is 5 core (l1,l2,l3, N,G) yet my driver only has l1, l2, l3, G. What do I do with Neutral?

Tags: three-phase

It's a motor driver and has connections for L1, L2, L3, and Ground -- by ground it's the universal ground symbol.

My three phase cable has five connectors. I'm not happy with leaving one out, so is this a convention for devices where N is wired in ground (as it connects to ground at some point!) or am I really connecting three live phases to ground? Surely this would trip any RCD?

Link to servo drive: https://www.se.com/ww/en/product/LXM52DU60C41000/lxm52-single-drive-1%2C5a-6a/

Comment: For a balanced load only 3 phases and ground are needed.

Comment: Which motor driver? Make and model? Link to manual? Which motor? Make and model? Link to manual?

Comment: Delta drives do not use the neutral, it's all between the phases

Answer (score 6):

Motor drives don't need neutral. So you don't have to wire neutral to them.
3+PE cable is sufficient.

[image]

If you have neutral on the drive end of the cable, don't connect it to anything and isolate it according to local regulations as unused core.

Answer (score 2):

Do not connect the neutral to anything. Refer to local codes for the proper marking and/or insulation of the unused wire. The neutral connection of the supply is likely connected to earth ground at the main circuit-breaker panel and should not be connected to earth anywhere else. The neutral connection is for single-phase loads that require the line-to-neutral voltage level. Those loads could be stand-alone loads or load elements within a piece of three-phase equipment. In this case, the instructions indicate no use of a neutral connection.

Answer (score 1):

A three phase motor generally don't have a neutral connection. The windings are usually connected either in a delta or a star configuration between the phases.